# What domain name to use?

Tags: discussion, top-7, poll, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/909/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name math.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/909/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

***Note:*** Please answer [this question asking us to describe in brief what our community is about](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/898/tell-us-what-your-community-is-about-in-one-brief-sentence), rather than suggesting domain names.  (— Isaac♦ 2010-10-05)

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using **big print** doesn't make your answers any better.

Comment: @bmargulies: It makes it easier to see *only* the domain name suggestions when scrolling through the page.

Comment: The rules are, **it has to be available**. 'Parked' != available. Would someone with privs please delete all the 'parked' answers, they just distract.

Comment: @bmargulies: See the [equivalent question](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be) on another stackexchange site. There is a quote from Joel that disagrees with you.

Comment: Indeed. I suspect I'm getting a lot of down-votes for that very misconception!

Comment: Wierd. I could have sworn that Jeff was the poster of the requirement that domains be completely unclaimed.

Comment: btw, is .com necessary? what about .info?

Comment: @mau: I would prefer .com over the other choices, except in the specific cases where edu, gov, org, mil, or net is justified, and I don't think any of those apply here. I would be opposed to info, biz, pro, and most of the country-specific TLDs. This is mostly an issue of reputation: many shady sites exist under such classifications, and few legitimate ones. A large majority of reputable sites exist under the .com TLD. A StackExchange/StackOverflow [blog post](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/domain-names/) outlines some guidelines for naming.

Comment: To be honest, reading through the list of proposals I find them all waaaaaaay worse than the current "math.stackexchange.com"! Do we *really* need to change the domain name?

Comment: (in fact, if someone managed to get hold of exchange.com, then math.exchange.com would be quite ideal...)

Comment: OK: it is pretty far in the future. I think it is safe to say that nobody's votes, answers, or edits to this proposal will be meaningful anymore. I am going to lock the thread for historical significance. (Note that, contrary to what the text in the lock says, this was a perfectly on topic question at the time it was asked.)

Answer (score 10):

Can't we just stay at

## math.stackexchange.com

?  I think it is better than all domain names suggested so far.

Comment: I agree that it is better than all of the names suggested before - I wonder what StackExchange has to say about it?

Comment: Then suggest a better one! Is math.stackexchange.com really the best name we could possibly have?

Comment: @Tom [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) is what StackExchange has to say about it

Comment: Borrrring. This is this is the worst suggestion I've yet seen.

Comment: Well, not as exciting as "mathsexchange"...

Answer (score 9):

## HilbertsHotel.com

Available

## HilbertsHotel.net

Available

Comment: I dont think it is parked anymore, [check this out](https://secure.registerapi.com/order/renew/auto.php?domain=hilbertshotel.com&campn=expired)... June 16 has come and gone.

Comment: @Tom: visit the URL yourself. It is parked by a company that parks expired domain names in order to sell them. (typically to the forgetful original owners)

Comment: I called around a bit and found out that somebody or some company has owned it previously - at this time their period of ownership has expired - but the name is sitting on hold in a 'grace period' until approximately August 31st.  If the original owner does not re-purchase this name then it becomes publicly available once again.  (The owner has apparently requested a "privacy clause" disallowing the person I spoke with to tell me who owns it... which is pretty ridiculous if they are trying sell something).

Comment: Conjecture: the original owner is actually a guy named Hilbert trying to start a chain of hotels.

Comment: Or just one infinitely large hotel, since he didn't bother to make the name plural.

Comment: This name is too esoteric to most people.

Comment: I agree that it is probably a bit esoteric to many people, including many professional mathematicians.

Comment: @Noldorin, @Kevin Lin: I respectfully disagree.  Hilbert's hotel has appeared in mainstream publications such as the NYT and is a piece of mathematical culture I think reasonably well-read people would have at least heard of, roughly analogous to Schrodinger's cat according to Google hits (and people make Schrodinger's cat jokes all the time, e.g. on Futurama!).  If not, it's still a memorable name, and it gives whoever comes across the site something to look up; they're learning already!

Comment: Although I dislike it (because I am not very familar with mathematical culture) I agree with Qiaochu, in that it can be used to create reasonably memorable branding. Think, Ask Jeeves.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Oh, I'm vaguely familiar with the term and I'm not a mathematician, but I suspect many amateurs wont' be. Either way, it's not really hinting enough at the site's general purpose.

Comment: **This.  Is.  Awesome.**

Answer (score 8):

## MathExchange.com

Boring, Simple, Parked

Comment: Not available. Taken.

Comment: Parked, to be precise. :)

Comment: This name makes me so grateful we don't use the British spelling.

Comment: @Kaestur: +1! That was one of the funniest things I've read in a while. =D!

Comment: Hah. I'm usually a fan of British English spelling, but indeed not here!

Comment: I kind of like the simplicity.

Comment: Come on people, let's show some creativity here! :)

Comment: I like the rhyme MathExchange / MathOverflow

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't get Kaestur's joke? I feel left out.

Comment: @BBischof:  MathsExchange/MathSexchange

Comment: Rofl, I thought he meant exchange had a British spelling! THats pretty funny.

Comment: Not just a joke: http://www.experts-exchange.com/

Comment: I like MathExchange. "Math" kind of rhymes with "stack". Or at least the vowel sound is the same.

Comment: @Kevin: That's why I don't like it; why should it sound like "Stack Exchange"?

Comment: Well, why shouldn't it?

Comment: @Kaestur: +1. I normally avoid this acronym, but LOL!

Comment: I dislike this because it does alienate the Brits! :P

Comment: If I could download this name twice, I would. I can't believe it's still at the top.

Comment: Which again raises the point: can we please let someone with a bit of creativity choose the name? (Are there any of the artsy sort on StackExchange!?)

Comment: @Noldorin: I always felt that mathematics requires a lot of creativity, yet I notice that almost all notable theorems/conjectures/formulas end up with a simple descriptive name or named after their creators. It is quite a mystery...

Comment: @Kaestur: Actually, you're right, it does.. but only at the very top level. (In this respect it's similar to the sciences.) The problem is, the field tends to attract predominantly the logical-sequential type of mind, rather than the holistic-creative type, which are most often (but not always) quite separate. The geniuses of the past (especially when maths was more a pursuit of polymaths) such as Newton, Gauss, and Lagrange were without doubt highly creative people, possessing a pretty broad intelligence. Unfortunately, the great majority in my experience are not - a tentative generalisation.

Comment: I appreciate the accuracy of MathExchange.com as a self-descriptor: this is after all a web-site in which math is being exchanged. I also don't think that any of the in-jokey names are good because they would be moreso alienating than inviting for the site's intended audience (who are at best mathematical amateurs and/or enthusiasts).

Answer (score 6):

## MarginTooSmall.com

Comment: Domain is available

Comment: I like it, but I don't know if the casual reader gets the joke.

Comment: I certainly don't...

Comment: @ricket http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem

Answer (score 3):

## AxiomFive.org

## AxiomFive.net

Available

(Not Available: AxiomFive.com)

The comprehension axiom that let in Russell's paradox.

Comment: I like "Axiom____"; it's catchy.  Not sure if Five is memorable enough; it might seem arbitrary.  But I like this train of thought.

Comment: I kind of like this actually.

Comment: @Justin: Axiom Five is euphonious, so I guess it probably will be fairly memorable.

Comment: After having this name stuck in my head all day, it will now get an enthused upvote from me.

Comment: Were it not of unwieldy length, just **UnrestrictedComprehension.com** would have a nice double meaning, both Russell's paradox and a nod to the purpose of the site, i.e. promoting comprehension.

Comment: I don't see the appeal..

Comment: This seems way too esoteric.

Comment: @Kevin Lin: Blame the influence of SO: Russell's paradox, like all forms of the liar paradox, holds a special place in the hearts of computer scientists and programmers in general, who live day-to-day in a world that choses inconsistency over incompleteness.

Comment: @camccann: Then we should purge the SO members from our ranks.

Comment: I'm with Kevin on this one, the name is a bit on esoteric side.

Comment: I like that it can be shortened to something distinctive like A5

Comment: I am still not sure what this title refers to. I wonder how many people will find out what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: I also am still unsure what this refers to. Actually, if I hadn't read this comment thread, I would have guessed that it's meant to refer to *Euclid*'s fifth axiom: the parallel postulate.

Comment: @Andrea, @Kevin: Axiom Five ("Axiom V") is explained in the SEP article, http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory, in the first paragraph containing "Frege".  Euclid made a distinction between definitions (Gk: οροι), postulates (αιτήματα), and axioms (κοιναι εννοιαι) - cf. http://mysite.du.edu/~etuttle/classics/nugreek/contents.htm; Euclid has an axiom five as well as postulate five, which is that the sum is more than the parts - not such a bad accidental association, really.

Answer (score 3):

## ForAllQThereExistsA.com

Available (though, of course, not valid for every consistent axiomatic system).

It'd be cooler as Unicode: ∀Q∃A.com

Answer (score 2):

## coffeeIntoTheorems.com

[available](http://www.coffeeIntoTheorems.com)

Comment: I think you ought to remove the second paragraph, so that it is possible to vote on the name itself.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Done.

Comment: This is the only name so far which is both original and understandable.

Comment: Interesting, but a bit too esoteric for my liking.

Comment: As the original poster of this name I would like to leave a comment about it...  Look at the edits to see my original purpose for suggesting this long, uninteresting name.  It is a cute phrase, but it is not a good name for a place.  In fact, **HilbertsHotel** is far better and should be voted up immediately by any reader of this comment.  Notice: **HilbertsHotel** actually sounds like a *destination*.

Answer (score 2):

## mathfactorial.com

With logo like math!.com

Answer (score 0):

### MathCommunity.com

Answer (score -1):

## OutNumbered.com

[Parked](http://www.outnumbered.com)

Answer (score -2):

## ConditionalPropositions.com

Answer (score -2):

## LogicalAxioms.com

Nerdy enough to be fun. Not terribly obvious. Available.

Answer (score -2):

### bijectivemapping.com

Answer (score -2):

### xisanumber.com

Comment: x is oftentimes a formal symbol representing an algebraically independent element over a ring R, such that R[x] is the polynomial ring in x.

Comment: If voting down comments were possible, I would.

Answer (score -2):

## proofbyexhaustion.com

Answer (score -2):

## Mathstack.com

Taken.

Sounds less overtly gawky/pompous than mathexchange.

Also: catchy(?), doesn't sound like it's trying too hard and has an implicit duality with Mathoverflow.

Comment: How about Stacksoverflow... =p

Comment: Oh wait Harry, just got your comment- was re: stacks (descent). Thought you were taking the proverbial...

Comment: Looks too much like "Mathslack" - esp. in poor screen fonts. The last thing we want is too attrack slack-ers.

Comment: @Tom Boardman: I'm still not exactly sure how else you could interpret it.

Comment: @Harry I thought you were mocking me for being uncreative (ie. 'well here's another variant on stackoverflow') My wholeheartiest apologies- am strangely on the defensive on this forum.

Comment: I was doing that too =p.  No apologies needed =)!

Answer (score -2):

## bijected.com

or surjected I suppose.

Answer (score -2):

## mathsmyths.com

(Available)

Comment: Doesn't pass the 'I know how to spell it just by hearing it' test for me. Math-smiths?

Comment: 'math's myths?'

Answer (score -2):

## finitesimplegroup.com

Like the [song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTby_e4-Rhg). Available.

Answer (score -2):

### TrivialQED.com

[avaliable](http://www.whois.net/whois/trvialqed.com)

Prove that P ≠ NP:

Trivial. Q.E.D.

Comment: QED is slightly confusing in that it also stands for quantum electrodynamics.

Answer (score -2):

## planeandsimple.com

hooray math puns. appears to be [parked](http://planeandsimple.com/)

Answer (score -2):

## ClassNumberOne

[Pun]

Comment: Available btw. And while I'm at it, some stupid ideas that don't really make it as answers but might be useful to the brainstorm atmosphere: 'Whoshavesthebarber', 'Ramanujanstaxi', 'Morphism', 'Mathdrain' and 'algebraicstackoveflow'...

Answer (score -2):

### primalities.com

(available)

Answer (score -2):

## IndependentAxiom.com

or

## UndecidableAxiom.com

Answer (score -2):

## NegativeEpsilon.com

Like in math joke "Let epsilon < 0".

Answer (score -2):

### UniMath.com

To emphasize university-level math.
Possible misreadings aren't bad:
universal math
united math ...

Answer (score -2):

### supersubset.com

(available)

Comment: Or maybe Superbset?

Answer (score -2):

### numbersoup.com

(available)

Answer (score -2):

## TertiumNonDatur.com

(taken, but unused)

The latin name of the statement "$A \vee \lnot A$ is true". Its a statement every mathematician knows, and has either used (or complained about.)

Also, it hints at "There are two good math sites."

Comment: I'm afraid this is the kind of joke one has to explain...

Answer (score -2):

## MathHub.com

Parked.

Answer (score -2):

## Mathematics4all.com

Parked.

Answer (score -2):

## ForEveryMathQ.com

Available. (as are .net, .org)

Answer (score -2):

**MathQuestions.[com|net|org]**

Taken [taken|taken].

Answer (score -2):

## AxiomaticPurity.com

[available](http://www.whois.net/whois/axiomaticpurity.com)

From [this xkcd comic](http://www.xkcd.com/435/)

Answer (score -2):

## mathematical.com

(Not Available)

Answer (score -2):

Upon reflection ...

## scitamehtam.com

Available.

Answer (score -2):

### mathmultiplier.com

A [force-multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_multiplier) for mathematics.

Answer (score -3):

## Mathalizer.com

Available.

Answer (score -3):

### convergentsequence.com

Answer (score -3):

## MathExhaustion.com

Solving math questions exhaustively.

Answer (score -3):

## AQEA.com

Closest we can get to ∀Q∃A, as [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-domain-name-to-use/333#333) suggests. Parked.

Comment: If we could get something like $\forall Q \exists A$, it may have a sense. Well, actually in that case $\forall \delta \exists \varepsilon$ would be nicer IMO. But this not being possible, it simply looks nonsense.

Comment: @Andrea: Actually, Unicode domain names are possible. See for example http://☃.net/

Comment: WOW!!! :-D I did not know that!

Comment: I suggested the written-out form "ForAllQThereExistsA" because, although Unicode is allowed in domains, it's not obvious how to enter it into a browser. Not that writing it all out is terribly convenient. I would be on board with the Unicode as the "official" domain, with "AQEA.com" and "ForAllQThereExistsA.com" re-directing there. Best of all worlds.

Answer (score -3):

## equationary.com

[available](http://www.whois.net/whois/equationary.com)

Answer (score -3):

## CounterExplanations.com

[available](http://www.whois.net/whois/counterexplanations.com)

Answer (score -3):

## NumeralLogic.com

[available](http://www.whois.net/whois/numerallogic.com)

Answer (score -3):

### addicted2math.com

(available at the moment)

Answer (score -3):

### mathpassage.com

(available at the moment)

Answer (score -4):

## MathLocus.com

Simple. Slightly mathy sounding. Available.

Comment: I vote against it because of a problem in German: "Locus" is a word for toilet (comparable to "John" in English, but less ambiguous).

Comment: damn you balpha, now I am going to be thinking of this every time i hear zero locus...

Answer (score -4):

### imaginarypart.com

Answer (score -4):

### mmmPi.com

[available](http://www.whois.net/whois/mmmpi.com)

Comment: Brilliant!  Best suggestion by a mile.

Answer (score -4):

### MathierThanYou.com

It's silly. But [available](http://www.whois.net/whois/mathierthanyou.com).

Answer (score -4):

### zeroequalsone.com

(available)

Answer (score -4):

### variablesoup.com

(available)

Answer (score -4):

## PrimeNumbers.com

Currently owned but only being used for redirection by a blogger. He may be willing to sell or donate.

Answer (score -4):

## pandnotp.com

another name along the lines of "math errors." currently [parked](http://www.pandnotp.com)

Answer (score -4):

## littlemissmath.com

available

Answer (score -4):

## TheEmptySet.com

Membership has its paradoxes.

(available as a "Premium Domain" at Godaddy)

Answer (score -5):

## MathUnderflow.com

Taken.

I'm not sure this is actually a good name, but it's certainly how the MathOverflow people are calling it for now.

Since at the moment, nobody can see Mariano's comment, which is buried at the bottom, I have reposted it here, since I think it should be seen:

> Well, no one complains that "undergraduates" is demeaning because it means "not good enough (yet?)"...

– Mariano Suárez-Alvarez (most recent comment)

Comment: As a frequent lurker, and a willing-yet-unable-to-contribute-to'er on MathOverflow, I kind of like this name.   (Yes, MathOverflow has lurkers.)

Comment: I worry that this is way too in-joke-y...

Comment: Not available (and neither is .net). Fitting name though.

Comment: I will call this site MathUnderflow regardless of whether or not that is the official name.

Comment: I downvoted. It makes sense to me, but what does it say to someone who has just come from Google?

Comment: It's a decent (amusing) name/pun, but it does sort of give a negative impression unless you know where it's coming from.

Comment: No! This name gives too much of an impression that this site is for people who "aren't good enough" for MathOverflow.

Comment: @Michael: Isn't that the point?

Comment: @Michael: It's sort of true though, if you're asking a question here, it's probably because it's not advanced enough for MO...

Comment: Well, the **point** of the site is not to be *less advanced* than Math Overflow, it is to **more open**.

Comment: No, false.  The point of this site is to be less advanced than mathoverflow.

Comment: @John: The point is to be less advanced and more open

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with Michael Lugo.

Comment: With all due respect, Kevin, isn't this site for people who don't have "good enough questions for mathoverflow"?

Comment: Well, no one complains that "undergraduates" is demeaning because it means "not good enough (yet?)"...

Comment: But "undergraduates" have a clear relationship to "graduates" and we (as a whole on the site) are not yet decided on our relationship to MO.  There is clearly a set of people who believe that the relationship exists to make MathUnderflow an appropriate name and there is also clearly a set of people who believe that the relationship does not exist in that way.

Comment: @97832123: You have variously applied "less advanced"/"good enough"/etc. to the questions, this site, and/or the people, and I don't know if you intended to apply it to all three.

Comment: And I thought "MathOverflow" was horribly unoriginal....

Comment: @Jens: Wait until you visit sinkoverflow...

Comment: This is my favorite by far! A lot of people already call it this too.

Comment: I own this domain(MathUnderflow.com), bought it so I could setup a site for all the questions rejected from mathoverflow but then never did.

Answer (score -5):

## assumeMath.com

[available](http://www.whois.net/whois/assumeMath.com)

Answer (score -5):

## setofallsets.com

Answer (score -5):

## MathUnderrun.com

...in nod to the "bigger brother" MathOverflow.

Comment: should surely be "**Underrun**"?

Comment: Whooops, thanks @Justin @Kaestur

Answer (score -5):

## anyerdosnumber.com

Answer (score -6):

### Mathulous.com

[Available](http://www.whois.net/whois/mathulous.com). And then there's also Mathulo.us (also [available](http://www.whois.net/whois/mathulo.us)).

Answer (score -6):

Okay, this one's way out there.

### TheThirdR.com

You know, like "reading, 'riting, 'rithmetic"? It's [available](http://www.whois.net/whois/thethirdr.com).

Answer (score -6):

### rationalpride.com

(available)

Answer (score -6):

### irnil.com

(available)

Comment: meaning 'not nil'.

Answer (score -6):

Alas, our British users may not be too happy with the name **mathexchange** since they write "math" as "maths" which, when replaced in said name, leads to a name one wouldn't want for the site.

Answer (score -7):

Passion for Math

## PassionForMath.com

Available.

Answer (score -7):

## piForTheWin.com

[available](http://www.whois.net/whois/piforthewin.com)

Comment: then why not piforthewin.com?

Comment: @Tomer Vromen: you're right there, sorry, I'm no native speaker, had it wrongly in mind...

Comment: pieforthewin.com mmm

Answer (score -7):

## MathDotCom.com

Comment: I really wanted to submit **ProofIsLeftToTheReader.com**.

Answer (score -7):

### xynkz.com

All your favorite variables smashed up together! Pronounced as 'zinks dot com', perhaps.

(available)

Answer (score -7):

### mmmpiforthewin.com

Not surprisingly, still available :-)

Comment: Seems like this one is asking for squatters to grab mmpiforthewin.com and mmmmpiforthewin.com...

Answer (score -9):

### Maaaaath.com

[available](http://www.whois.net/whois/maaaaath.com). no comment.