# 'What domain name to use?' Brainstorm

Tags: discussion, top-7

#### Problem

Okay so [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-domain-name-to-use) is clearly an important question and a real head-scratcher at that- from what I've seen, with no one proposal at over 4 votes, we still seem to be miles from *the* answer (if such a thing exists). Now, the [SO blog on domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) suggests we brainstorm (ie. no hold's barred, every name we can think of, shove it out there); and I don't think the original thread qualifies as that at the moment: there are now 48 answers, most of which noone newly voting/coming up with ideas will read and the SE system's bias toward questions with a single answer is kicking in big time and ruining any discursive quality.

#### Proposal

So I suggest a minor hacklet: we should keep that thread for voting on answers that are good enough to make it there and use this one for blue sky/outside of box/ radical thinking- somewhere we can put all of our dumb ideas down until something awesome appears. We do this by assembling a few community wiki answers, filled with similarly themed names from the original question, and add similar stuff that occurs to us as we go. If you sepecially like something leave a comment and if you especially like an overall theme feel free to vote the answer containing it up.

#### Rules

Ideally put really similar names together, don't erase anyone's name-idea, if you have an idea you don't think fits in any of the answers, try hard to make it fit, otherwise we'll have the same problem again.

Comment: I'm under the impression that MathUnderflow has simultaneously the most votes up and down.  I rather like it a lot, and I think it captures rather well what the community is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @97832123: Actually, that's not true. Checking just now, Mathunderflow has 17 up, 15 down, while dividebyzero has 19 up, 17 down. Mathexchange is not far behind with 15 up, 11 down.

Comment: I don't understand who thinks that "dividebyzero" is any good at all. It's so lame and off-point.

Comment: I'd favour a name which doesn't include the words *maths* or *math*, because either way you alienate half your audience. *Mathematics* would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

#### Maths Puns

- [LeftAsAnExercise](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/e/exerciseleftasan.html)<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1 `.com` is [taken](http://www.leftasanexercise.com/); other TLDs are [available](http://www.domainsbot.com/results.aspx?q=leftasanexercise).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

#### Maths References

Comment: Bourbaki's Grotto.  Haha.  Lame.

Comment: +1. I would really hope we can come with a name that has a mathematics reference in it.

Comment: Even more boring.

Comment: @Noldorin: "Maths references" isn't the proposed name here; it's the proposed genre of name.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But there have already been plenty of names with maths references in them (not least my own suggestion). It's hardly novel.

Comment: If there are plenty of names with maths references, edit this answer and add them.

Answer (score 1):

#### Variations on Math/Stack Overflow

- MathExchange
- Mathunderflow
- Mathstack

Comment: Why should the name be a variation on Stack Overflow (a term that has meaning to programmers and is good for the programming questions website, but is irrelevant here) or Stack Exchange (just the name of the software running the site, rather than describing its contents)?

Comment: All terrible, and boring as hell.

Comment: I also agree with ShreevatsaR here, 'stack' and 'overflow' are both very programming-specific, there's nothing generic about them. 'MathExchange' is the only one that even makes sense logically, but yeah...

Answer (score 0):

MathCommunity.com